# XML is blank after applying XLST transformation to it?

Tags: xml, xslt

Not sure if I'm missing something here since this is my first time doing this. Both files are in the same folder if that matters (xml and xsl).

Example of the xml:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cd_catalog.xsl"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD> 
</CATALOG>
```

And my xsl file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/CD">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ARTIST"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="YEAR"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="PRICE"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What are you using to apply the transformation?

Comment: Can't say I even know what that means, I just got the xml file, and I created the xsl by hand. I figured having both in the same folder and opening the xml would be enough, but apparently not.

Comment: Opening the XML in what application?

Comment: I opened it in chrome, doesn't work. However, opening the tutorial file on w3 works fine, shows the table.

Comment: Chrome (and most modern browsers) do not allow XSLT transformations from local files . Do a search - it's a quite common issue.

Comment: Huh, didn't know that. Thanks.